# How to save CRLF (/r/n) into '&#13;&#10' - decimal format instead of '&#xD;&#xA' -hexadecimal format in XML file from C# application?

Tags: xml

The /r/n or the new line is converted in &#xD;&#xA; (Hexadecimal) instead of &#13;&#10; (Decimal) in Windows production environment.

The same code converts /r/n as &#13;&#10; (Decimal) as required/expected in my local environment.

C# code:

```
XElement xelm = *******; //Contains xml text with /r/n
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
xdoc.add(xelm);

using(var strWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
{
  xdoc.Save(strWriter);
}
```

I tried replacing text containing /r/n into &#13;&#10;  `.Replace("\r\n", "&#13;&#10;");` but it is not successful in production server and saving in hexadecimal format.

Could anyone please suggest a solution where the code saves the data in decimal format (&#13;&#10;) in all the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Both are equally valid and both will be accepted by any XML parser, which is why most XML serialisers don't give you any control over this. (They tend to assume that the XML will be read using a real XML parser, though we know from this site that lots of people attempt to process XML "by hand", usually with bad results).

The Saxon serializer [disclaimer: my company's product] is one of the few I know of that gives you a choice (there's a vendor serialisation property called `saxon:character-representation`. You could post-process using that if you really need this level of control.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. The reason behind the question is, the XML that we are accessing is a common resource file shared for all the users. People edit the data frequently and try to check in to GIT and there will be a merge conflict as few users save it in Decimal format and others in Hexa decimal. And we need to save the XML file in the same format for all users which is not happening

Comment: Fair enough. No easy answer. Not from me, anyway.